# Use a constant as options for select box in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, constants

I have a model (`Bar`) that requires a list of ethnic attributes that may apply to the record. The model is a nested attribute of model `Foo` (I don't think that matters, but just being thorough...). Rather than create a model to manage this short list, I've defined a constant in my application. I can then reference that constant in validations, etc. It works fine when validating the model - all my tests are passing green.

I can also see the list of values in the view (in the `new.html.haml` view for the `Bar` model). I can select among those items, and the parameters look correct. However, the value selected is not posting to the database.

The model `Bar` has a column `:ethnicity` of type:string. The constant used to define the range of options is:

```
ETHNIC_GROUPS = [nil, "African American/Black", "American Indian", "Hispanic", "Puerto Rican",
      "Alaskan Native", "Asian American/Pacific Islander", "Mexican American/Chicano"]
```

In the view file I've created a selection box for the model:

```
#app/views/bar/new.html.haml

  = form_for([@foo, @bar]) do |f|
    # form elements omitted

    = f.label :ethnicity
    = f.select :ethnicity, CommonConstants::ETHNIC_GROUPS

    = f.submit "Create New Bar"
```

In the front end, I see the options in the ETHNIC_GROUPS constant available for selection. After selecting an element, the parameters appear correct:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: "✓"
authenticity_token: YKvYw3T6q+6DsLA6qdH2yYvFtDAOuBFggCMDclIHlvQ0DvJbZqSdniLMZCivmWINjb3ZoCVWF890Mu4vB3VHrw==
bar: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  name: Test Hispanic Selection

  # parameters omitted for clarity

  ethnicity: Hispanic

  # parameters omitted for clarity

  notes: ''
commit: Add New Bar
controller: bars
action: create
foo_id: '4'
```

As far as I can see, everything in the parameters looks exactly correct. However, after successfully creating that record, there is nothing in the database in the ethnicity column. A SQL query (in postgres) shows this:

```
select name, ethnicity from bar;

                       name                        | ethnicity
----------------------------------------------------+-----------
 African American                                   |
 American Indian                                    |
 Hispanic                                           |
```

Just for good measure, here are the validations for Bar:

```
#app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  validates :ethnicity, inclusion: { in: CommonConstants::ETHNIC_GROUPS }, allow_nil: true
end
```

I'm really stumped here. Can't figure out why the value in the selection array defined by the constant isn't passing through to the database - even though it appears to be passing into the params hash.

** EDIT **

Just thought to add the html in case that is helpful:

```
<select name="bar[ethnicity]" id="bar_ethnicity">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="African American/Black">African American/Black</option>
  <option value="American Indian">American Indian</option>
  <option value="Hispanic">Hispanic</option>
  <option value="Puerto Rican">Puerto Rican</option>
  <option value="Alaskan Native">Alaskan Native</option>
  <option value="Asian American/Pacific Islander">Asian American/Pacific Islander</option>
  <option value="Mexican American/Chicano">Mexican American/Chicano</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you whitelisted the param in your controller?

Comment: #facepalm! That's it. Completely overlooked that as a potential cause. If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you have whitelisted the `ethnicity` param:

```
def bar_params
  params.require(:bar).permit(:ethnicity) # ...
end
```